# Name of Sisera's Mother

Tags: sources-mekorot, shofar, shoftim--book-of

The mother of Sisera seems to take on a fairly large role [[see Rosh Hashana (33b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.33b.10?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)] in understanding blowing the Shofar on Rosh Hashana, based on her crying for her son after his war against Klal Yisroel [[Shoftim (5:28)]](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.5.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). In fact, one of the reasons we blow the shofar 100 times on Rosh Hashana is due to her wails [[Aruch (דק p. 119)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51750&st=&pgnum=122&hilite=)]. However, I haven't seen her name mentioned once in Chazal, Rishonim, or Achronim. Do any Jewish sources tell us the name of the "mother of Sisera"?

Comment: Rav Chaim Kanievsky *shilta*'s *sefer* **LeMachseh Atik** is perfect for this kind of question, as it's all about giving the names/dates/ages of various people from *Midrashim* and *Chazal*. I did a quick check and he doesn't address it. I don't know if that's proof that it doesn't exist, at least in *Chazal*.

Comment: According to [Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%90#%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%94), Pseudo-Philo (Kadmoniyot Hamikra) calls her by the name "Tamach" (תמך).

Comment: Following your link to the Aruch on the word "dak", I see Sisera's mother mentioned but nothing about the 100 wails. Am I misreading something? Tosefot on Rosh Hashana quote a different entry, on "arav", that indeed mentions it: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48234&st=&pgnum=264

Comment: Why would/should the role Sisera's mother [unwittingly] played in determining how the shofar is blown affect whether her name is remembered? In fact, she played a very minor role even in the story she appeared in. The ones who actually affected the count and the style of the shofar blowing, were the ones who said about her "ותיבב". [Their names are known](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.5.1?lang=bi&lang2=en): [Deborah the Prophetess and Judge, wife of Lappidot, and Barak, son of Abinoam of Kedesh in Naphtali](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.4.4-6?lang=bi&lang2=en).

Answer (score 4):

"Temach" or "Tamach" [image: Yalkut Me'Am Loez, Softim 5/28]

Comment: Note: [Ezra 2:53](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2.53?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he)

Comment: You know, one could read "שאמו של סיסרא **תמח שמה**" as to say "_that Sisera's mother - **may her name be blotted out**_".

Comment: @TamirEvan - Interesting, but would that fit into the next word of the statement "And ..."?

Comment: @פריזהב I was just trying (unsuccessfully) to be [punny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun). [@harel13's comment to the question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117481/name-of-siseras-mother/117489?noredirect=1#comment389008_117481) basically confirms your understanding, with the 'ח' exchanged for the similar sounding 'ך'.

Comment: The "ספר קדמון" is probably the Pseudo-Philo (Kadmoniyot Hamikra) @harel13 mentions in that same comment.